# Difference between fire and publish

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

In the context of YUI3 custom events : what is the difference between Y.fire and Y.publish ?

Answer (score 5):

Publish creates a new custom event, while fire will trigger it, read the specs here:

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/EventTarget.html#method_publish

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/EventTarget.html#method_fire

Comment: Y.fire will also publish an event if it has not previously been published. You just lose the ability to customize the details of that event.